# ngrx does not return the correct type of element in select (object is wrapped)

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I started playing with ngrx today, because I want to use it for our new page. I struggled for quite a while with the setup, or still am, to be more precise.

I can now dispatch an event to the store and get it using a select back out. But what I get back out is not the correct object. Let me show some code:

*app.module.ts*

```
...
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      template: templateReducer
    })
  ]
```

*app.state.ts*

```
export interface AppState {
  template: Pages;
}
```

*template.actions.ts*

```
export interface TemplateState {
  template: Pages;
}

const initialState: TemplateState = {
  template: null
};

export function templateReducer(state = initialState, action: TemplateActions): TemplateState {

  switch (action.type) {

    case TemplateActionTypes.ADD_FULL_TEMPLATE: {
        return Object.assign({}, { template: action.payload as Pages });
    }

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

*template.actions.ts*

```
export const TemplateActionTypes = {
  ADD_FULL_TEMPLATE: '[Store] Add template'
}

export class AddFullTemplateAction implements Action {
  type = TemplateActionTypes.ADD_FULL_TEMPLATE;
  constructor(public payload: Pages) {
  }
}
```

*page.component.ts*

```
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
  this.store.dispatch(new AddFullTemplateAction(['1', '2'])
}

ngOnInit() {

  this.store.select((store) => store.template).subscribe( (data) => {
    console.log(data); // gives "{ template: ['1','2'] }"
    console.log(data.template); // already forbidden by typescript because data is of type Pages which is an array
    console.log((data as any).template); // gives my desired output "['1', '2']"
  });

}
```

So somewhere along the line my code with ngrx messes up the object chain. Does anyone see what goes wrong here?

Comment: `this.data.template` should be `data.template`, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes sorry, typo in the question, that doesn't solve the problem though, thanks, I fix it

Comment: What if you set subscribe( (data:Template) =>  TypeScript is guessing the datatype if ur not providing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it turns out to be a config issue with naming problems.

In *app.state.ts* I should have referenced `template`as a reference to the template state like this:

```
export interface AppState {
  templateState: TemplateState;
}
```

and in the *app.module.ts* the name of the loaded reducer must be the same as in the `AppState`:

```
...
@NgModule({

imports: [
  StoreModule.forRoot({
    templateState: templateReducer
  })
]
```